# asio::io_service.run() exits despite work object

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a dispatcher class (stripped implementation below) which creates an I/O service and allows the start worker threads which will execute `io_service` handlers. These threads should stay active until I tell them to stop. For that I use an `io_service::work` object. However, these threads do not stay active, despite the presence of the work object. Any idea on how to use `io_service::work` correctly?

This is a minimal working example that shows the problem (`DispatcherClass` given underneath):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void myDispatcherMainThread(DispatcherClass &dispatcher)
{
    std::cout << "Dispatcher Started\n";
    dispatcher.AddCtrlCHandling();
    if (dispatcher.Run(2))
        std::cout << "Dispatcher is about to finish (expected).\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Dispatcher is about to finish (unexpected).\n";
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    DispatcherClass dispatcher;
    boost::thread maindispatcherthread(myDispatcherMainThread,boost::ref(dispatcher));
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    if (dispatcher.get_io_service().stopped())
        std::cout << "Dispatcher should not have finished!";

    dispatcher.cleanStop();
    maindispatcherthread.join();
}
```

This is the dispatcher class (put here to make this post readable):

```
class DispatcherClass : private boost::noncopyable {
public:
    DispatcherClass():
      _ioService(),
      _pKeepWorking(new boost::asio::io_service::work( _ioService )),
      _expectingdispatchend(false){}

    boost::asio::io_service &get_io_service() { return _ioService; }

    // Start the dispatcher threads
    bool Run(unsigned int numThreads = -1)
    {
        // Recover after a clean stop
        if (!_pKeepWorking)
            _pKeepWorking.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work( _ioService ));

        // Reset after clean or forced stop
        if (_ioService.stopped())
        {
            _expectingdispatchend = false;
            _ioService.reset();
        }

        // Start message dispatch threads
        boost::thread_group workerThreads;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ((numThreads == (unsigned int)-1) ? (boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()) : numThreads); ++i)
            workerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&DispatcherClass::WorkerThread, this));

        // Wait until all threads finish
        workerThreads.join_all();

        return _expectingdispatchend;
    }

    // Stop the dispatcher threads
    void Stop()
    {
        _expectingdispatchend = true;
        _ioService.stop();
    }

    void cleanStop()
    {
        _expectingdispatchend = true;
        _pKeepWorking.reset();
    }

    // Stop the dispatcher threads on CTRL-C
    void AddCtrlCHandling()
    {
        boost::asio::signal_set sig_set(_ioService, SIGTERM, SIGINT);
        sig_set.async_wait(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::stop, boost::ref(_ioService)));
    }

private:
    bool _expectingdispatchend;

    boost::asio::io_service _ioService;
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service::work > _pKeepWorking;

    void WorkerThread()
    {
        while (true) {
        try
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            _ioService.run(ec);
            break;
        }
        catch (const std::exception &) {}
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Same behavior if you call `Run(1)`?  Also, what exactly is the output, as it will help us to find our way through the execution path?  What is the value of `ec` when the threads terminate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) is being invoked within the cancelled `SignalHandler`, causing all invocations of `io_service::run()` to return as soon as possible.

```cpp
void DispatcherClass::AddCtrlCHandling()
{
    boost::asio::signal_set sig_set(...);
    sig_set.async_wait(boost::bind(
        &boost::asio::io_service::stop, boost::ref(_ioService)));
}
```

In `DispatcherClass::AddCtrlCHandling()`, the `sig_set` is an automatic variable with a type of [`boost::asio::signal_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html) with its lifetime ending once the function returns.  In the `signal_set` destructor, all outstanding asynchronous wait operations on the `signal_set` will be completed with an error code of `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.  Hence, a `SignalHandler` that will invoke `io_service::stop()` is queued into the `io_service` and invoked by one of the worker threads.  To resolve this, consider extending the `signal_set`'s lifetime by making `sig_set` a member variable of `DispatcherClass`.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks! I added a `sig_set` shared pointer member so that in the `cleanStop` method I could destroy the signal set, otherwise calling `cleanStop` would have no effect. In fact this makes the work object redundant (at least if I always install the CTRL-C handling, i.e. remove the AddCtrlCHandling method and add the sig_set.async_wait in the run method).

Answer (score 0):

To narrow it down: Your threads instantly terminate after starting:

```
 boost::system::error_code ec;
 _ioService.run(ec); // <----- blocks until the work is complete
 break;
```

It seems to me that there is no work to be done, so `run` returns almost instantly (showing `system:0` for the error code, which seems to be OK).

I'm not familiar with asio's API but I guess that the underlying problem is that `_ioService` is not properly set up before you spawn your threads.